# How to set expiry date on pop-up in javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup, local-storage

I have a modal which appears once per user , and I am using local storage to achieve this. However, I am now trying to make it so that after a certain date ( 1/03/2022) to not appear at all. Here is my logic at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var key = 'hadModal',
  hadModal = localStorage.getItem(key);

    if (!hadModal) {
        $('#PIAModal').modal('show');
    }
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem(key, true);
        $("#PIAModal").modal('hide');

    });

    $(".modal").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem(key, true);
        $("#PIAModal").modal('hide');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function to check if it's the due date and pass it to the conditional

```
function isBeforeDate() {
  let today = new Date();
  const endDate = new Date("2022-03-01");

  if (today < endDate) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}


if (!hadModal && isBeforeDate()) {
    $('#PIAModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one for future reference

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Date` objects in Javascript and compare them.

```
var now = new Date();
var end = new Date("2022-03-01");

if (now < end) {
     $('#PIAModal').modal('show');
}
```